# Request failed with status code 429

Tags: solidity, ether, javascript, api, bot

I've find a bot on Github and when I try to make it work, he do one or 2 request and I received the error: Request failed with status code 429
How can I fix that. The node that I use can received 1500 request/min.

Comment: Can you share the github repo? Probably you need to change the rpc provider.